# Simple Localstorage/jQuery function

Tags: jquery, local-storage

First off: I've been a big fan of Stackoverflow and its community because it has helped me understanding HTML and the new HTML5.

Now here's my question: I have to make a mobile app where i use a localstorage function with jQuery. It can be as simple as it sounds: There is an input field with a submit button, and when the input is submitted, it is added to a list. There is a button in front of every li-item so it can be erased from the list. jQuery is preferred, but javascript can be used as well.

Here's my start (i hope im doing this good):

```
<form name="input" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="fav" class="stored" required> <button>
</form>

<ul>
<button><li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I dont know how i can use jQuery/localstorage to create the function..

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a plugin like [jStorage](http://www.jstorage.info/).